# Xamarin and dotNetRdf

Tags: c#, xamarin, sparql, rdf, dotnetrdf

I'm trying to query DBpedia with Xamarin using `dotNetRdf`

This is my code:

```
  SparqlRemoteEndpoint endpoint = new SparqlRemoteEndpoint(new Uri("http://dbpedia.org/sparql"), "http://dbpedia.org");

  //Make a SELECT query against the Endpoint
  SparqlResultSet results = endpoint.QueryWithResultSet("SELECT DISTINCT ?Concept WHERE {[] a ?Concept}");
  foreach (SparqlResult result in results)
  {
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
  }

  //Make a DESCRIBE query against the Endpoint
  IGraph g = endpoint.QueryWithResultGraph("DESCRIBE ");
  foreach (Triple t in g.Triples)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
  }
```

This code works great on a C# project, but inside Xamarin i have the following error on `QueryWithResultSet`:

```
void SparqlRemoteEndpoint.QueryWithResultSet(string query, SparqlResultsCallback callback, object state)(+1 overload)
Makes a Query asynchronously where the expected Result is a SparqlResultSet i.e. SELECT and ASK Queries
```

I can't understand what callback i need to create.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all platforms support synchronous HTTP operations so all platforms that do not support this you need to use the asynchronous method instead.

This is a limitation of the .Net platform that they chose to not support the same set of APIs across all platforms